# How to automatically change file names for all file added to a directory?

Tags: macos, script, rename

I've created a folder in dropbox for all my screenshots, and redirected all my screenshots there.

However the default screenshots file name are long (it contains a time stamp and I don't see how to remove that). I'm wondering if I can use some shell script or applescript to do this.

Also I need it only change the names of newly added files. I've tried automator, but it keep renaming all files in that folder. E.g. 01.png may become 03.png after adding other files to that folder, which make correct dropbox reference literally impossible.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the file names? (With the date in the name)?

Comment: In principle you can do this using Folder Actions and AppleScript, but those don't work reliably if there are several files changed in quick succession.

Comment: @Hennes e.g. "Screenshot 2012-07-26 上午10.40.25" It contains Chinese character.

Comment: I can't seem to figure it out. I was toying with something like this from a shell `for a in * ; do echo -n "Moving" $a "to " ; (echo $a | cut -c1-10,25-26,28-29,31-32) ; done`  (Obviously a literal cut and paste just echos text rather than execute a mv)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple bash script you can use:

```
#!/bin/bash

#
# Rename a folder of images using a prefix in a numbered sequence
#
# @author Henry Tseng
# Jul 27, 2012
#

# Retrieve 
if [ ! -d "$1" ]
then
    echo "rename_files: \"$1\" is not a directory"
    exit
fi

# Rename set
echo "Renaming"

FILES="$1*"
N=0

for f in $FILES
do
    N=`expr $N + 1`
    echo " $f"
    RCMD="mv '$f' $1img_$N.jpg" 
    eval $RCMD
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the commercial [Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php) tool.

Just create a rule that looks like the following:

[image: Screenshot of applicable rule]

The result will look like this, with numbers appended due to *rename automatically* selected in *Options*:

[image: Folder containing sequentially named image files]

Comment: Great! Is it possible to do it using Quicksilver?

Comment: @hyh Hazel and Quicksilver are fundamentally different tools. That's like asking how to do something in Firefox when the answer talks about Microsoft Word. Just download Hazel and see for yourself how it works.

Comment: so Hazel is an app just for organizing folders? Then $25 seems expensive. I'd like to find some hack to do this by myself.